# How to calculate the cell potential after the reaction has operated long enough for the Fe2+ to have changed by some concentration?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, reduction-potential

> Consider the cell described below at $\pu{261 K}$:
>
> $$\ce{Fe | Fe^2+ (\pu{0.925 M}) || Cd^2+ (\pu{0.981 M}) | Cd}$$
>
> Given $E^\circ_\ce{Cd^2+ -> Cd} = \pu{-0.403 V}$, $E^\circ_\ce{Fe^2+ -> Fe} = \pu{-0.441 V}$.
> Calculate the cell potential after the reaction has operated long enough for the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to have changed by $\pu{0.383 mol L-1}$.

I have

$$E_\mathrm{cell} = (0.441 - 0.403) - \frac{0.0591}{2}\ln\left(\frac{0.925}{ 0.981}\right) = 0.03974$$

but I'm not sure how to find the $E_\mathrm{cell}$ when the $\ce{Fe2+}$ concentration has changed by $\pu{0.383 mol L-1}$.

Comment: What are the concentrations of the ions at that point? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "changed by 0.383 mol/L". Is it increasing or decreasing?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Are you using the natural or the base-10 logarithm?

Comment: I'm using the natural log

Comment: It's either R T / z F ln(Q) or 0.0591 V / z log(Q). For your formula, the term is too large by a factor 2.303 = ln(10).

Comment: As the reaction proceeds towards equilibrium, the cell potential approaches zero. This is one way of figuring out which concentration increases and which decreases. Or you write down the chemical equation of the reaction in the direction it proceeds and work from there.